# Set a maximum cell value in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to add cells a-d and then do something like add cell (e/22) but not return something greater than 1.0

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 =if(sum(A1:D1)+(E1/22)>1,[INSERT ALTERNATIVE VALUE HERE],sum(A1:D1)+(E1/22))
```

Comment: Commas should be semicolons.

Answer (score 18):

For setting a min, wrap your formula with a MAX(original formula; min value) and to set a max limit do MIN(original formula; max value). In the example you gave it wil be MAX(your formula; 0) turning to MAX(-20; 0) which is 0.

To set both boundaries in same cell, do MAX(MIN(original formula; max value); min value).

This is not specific to spreadsheets, it is generic math.

Answer (score 0):

Set maximum cell value on input(validation)

Data => Data validation
Criteria: Number